# Generating UUID in response to message sent by Kafka Producer

Tags: c, apache-kafka, producer

I am trying to develop an application which reads byte arrays (representing a C structure and each array associated with a UUID) from a Cache and sends it to Kafka Server through a Producer application in C.

The kafka producer application accumulates a fixed number of such packets and sends them at once.

What I wish to accomplish is get an acknowledgment that which of the messages in the batch were successfully delivered and get their UUID back so that I can clear them from my cache application. I am new to kafka, Please guide me as what is the best way to get this done.

Answer (score 1):

Why not create another consumer topic that 'listens' for messages that have been acknowledged, and then removes them from the cache.  Then the producer can just push messages to that topic when required.

Answer (score 1):

When sending messages to Kafka, you can configure your Producer to request acknowledgments (usually exposed as a config called `acks`). That allows the producer to know if a message was successfully or not.

For example, with [`librdkafka`](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka) (in my opinion the best C Kafka client) you can get a delivery report callback when a produce request completes. It contains the message and an error in case of failure. That should enable you to easily identify which messages where sent successfully and mark them as done.

See the [`rd_kafka_conf_set_dr_msg_cb`](https://github.com/mimaison/librdkafka/blob/master/src/rdkafka.h#L1016-L1035) method to configure a delivery report callback. The [simple producer example](https://github.com/mimaison/librdkafka/blob/master/examples/rdkafka_simple_producer.c) demonstrate its usage.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have implemented the example. After every delivery I get a response as "XX bytes delivered successfully." When I send 10,000 messages the callbacks are delayed and messages are enqueued continuously. Now when I later receive multiple callbacks at once, I am unable to decide which message it is referring to. Can I attach some UUID to each message and get that UUID back in callback to know which message is response referring to ? This will help me later clear cache. Can I also customize batches myself to know which packets were included in a particular batch.

Comment: You get a pointer to the message (`rd_kafka_message_t *`) in the delivery report, so you can check the message content. You can also specify an opaque (for example set it to the UUID) when producing (`rd_kafka_produce`) and the opaque will be set in the delivery report.